# php7.2-fpm timeout nginx wsl 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, fastcgi, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu wsl 16.04 to 18.04.

Once it was finished I resumed my local development, happy to find (almost)
everything working.

For some reason, I now get this error with php-fpm

`2018/09/19 21:17:26 [error] 3736#3736: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: ::1, server: _, request: "GET /register HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"`

Here are the relevant contents of my  /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file.

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

            # With php7.0-cgi alone:
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php7.0-fpm:
            #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }
```

And the relevant lines in /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

`listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`

I also tried to uncomment the 
`listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1`
but still the same.

There must be something I'm missing here. The www.conf file was reset to default during the upgrade, it has to be something in there. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could this be related to the [libsodium-php module timing out issue](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php/issues/94) on some cloud services (linode, digital ocean?)  Did you try `apt install haveged` per the discussion on that thread?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to put this in the location block of my nginx configuration:

```
fastcgi_buffering off;
```

on the first line

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration below for Nginx which come from [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/393#issuecomment-442498519)

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_buffering off; # This must be here for WSL as of 11/28/2018
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 20M \n post_max_size=21M";
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

}
```